# Tool to auto-format shell script

Tags: text-formatting

I got some code above which was into a pdf document, wherever I try to post it indentation is terrible, I would like to get it to a proper formatting for debbuging. Here is my code:

```
    #!/bin/bash 
# to measure average power consumed in 30sec with 1sec sampling interval 
duration
=
30 
interval
=
1 
RAILS
=(
"
VDD_IN /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0041/iio:device1/in_power0_input" 
  "VDD_SYS_GPU /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0040/iio:device0/in_power0_input" 
  "VDD_SYS_CPU /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0041/iio:device1/in_power1_input" 
  "VDD_SYS_SOC /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0040/iio:device0/in_power1_input" 
  "VDD_SYS_DDR /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0041/iio:device1/in_power2_input" 
 "VDD_4V0_WIFI /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/ina3221x/0-
0040/iio:device0/in_power2_input"
)
for
((
i 
=
 0
;
 i 
<
 ${#RAILS[@]}
;
 i++
));
do
Optimizin
g Jetson TX2 for Power and Performance
Jetson TX2
TDG
-08413-
001_v1.0  
|     28 
read
name
[
$i]
 node
[
$i]
 pwr_sum
[
$i]
 pwr_count
[
$i]
<<<$(echo 
"${RAILS[$i]} 0 0")
done
end_time
=$(($(date '+%s')
+
 duration
))
while
[
$(date '+%s')
-
le 
$end_time
];
do
for
((
i 
=
 0
;
 i 
<
 ${#RAILS[@]}
;
 i++
));
do
    pwr_sum
[
$i]=$((
${pwr_sum[$i]} 
+
$(cat ${node[$i]})))
&&
      pwr_count
[
$i]=$((
${pwr_count[$i]} 
+
 1
))
done
sleep
$interval
done
echo
"RAIL,POWER_AVG" 
for
((
i 
=
 0
;
 i 
<
 ${#RAILS[@]}
;
 i++
));
do
  pwr_avg
=$((
${pwr_sum[$i]} 
/
 ${pwr_count[$i]}
))
echo
"${name[$i]},$pwr_avg" 
done
```

I'm doign it manually but I wonder if it could be done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

What IDE are you using? In VIM, `gg=G` works reasonably well. If you're using Atom, then see this: https://atom.io/packages/format-shell .

Comment: True, but OP has a lot of lines that need to be joined together before `=`.  I think it's worth mentioning you can select a range of lines with visual line mode (`shift + V`, `j` and `k` to move up and down), then join them with `J`.

Comment: how do I use gg=G in vim?

Comment: How to use gg=G: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12582414/487992

Comment: gg=G does not work on my complex Bash script at all :)

Answer (score 1):

[format-shell](https://atom.io/packages/format-shell) uses `shfmt` (https://github.com/mvdan/sh) under the hood. This tool could be plugged to CI or as `pre-commit` hook